# Injecting Dependency programmatically asp.net core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm just starting with `Asp.net core` *Dependency Injection*, and my concept could be inaccurate. [This docs.asp.net post](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection.html) explains how to inject context to a controller. I have little confusion regarding injection, in testing perspective. Assume we have following scenario:

```
public interface ITasksRepository
{ 
   public void Create();
}

//This is fake implementation, using fake DbContext for testing purpose
public class TasksRepositoryFake : ITasksRepository
{
   public void Create()
   {
     FakeDbContext.Add(sometask);
     //logic;
   }
}

//This is actual implementation, using actual DbContext
public class TasksRepository : ITasksRepository
{
   public void Create()
   {
     DbContext.Add(someTask);
     //logic;
   }
}
```

Now in order to inject context in controller, we design it as:

```
public class TasksController : Controller
{
    public ITasksRepository TaskItems { get; set; }

    public TodoController(ITaskRepository taskItems)
    {
        TaskItems = taskItems;
    }
    //other logic
 }
```

What asp.net `core` provides as builtin feature is, we can register the dependency injection in startup class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepositoryFake>();
}
```

According to this logic, my `TaskRepositoryFake` will be injected to the controller. So far, everything is clear. My questions/confusions regarding this are as follows:

**Questions:**

- How can I use this builtin DI feature to inject the context using some logic? May be programatically, or configuration based, or environment based? *(for example, always inject fake context, when using 'test' environment? etc.)*
- Is it even possible? If we always have to change this manually in *StartUp* class, then how does this builtin DI feature serve us? Because we could have simply done that in controller, without this feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First to answer your question: Yes, you can inject the dependency programmatically. By using factories, as is always the case with injecting dependencies based on run-time values. The AddSingleton has an overload which takes an implementationfactory and so a basic example for your use case looks like:

```
   public class Startup
{
    public bool IsTesting { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        IsTesting = env.EnvironmentName == "Testing";
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ISomeRepository>(sp => IsTesting ? (ISomeRepository)new SomeRepository() : (ISomeRepository) new FakesomeRepository());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ISomeRepository someRepository)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello World from {nameof(someRepository)}!");
        });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

The concerning line of code for your TasksRepository would look like:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITaskRepository>(sp => isTesting?(ITasksRepository)new TasksRepositoryFake(): (ITasksRespository)new TasksRepository() );
```

Even better would be to put it in a factory (again with my example):

```
services.AddSingleton<ISomeRepository>(sp => SomeRepositoryFactory.CreatSomeRepository(IsTesting));
```

I hope you see how this helps you setting it up config based, environment based, or however you want.
I you are interested I wrote more about DI based on run-time values via abstract factories [here](https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/real-world-example-of-dependency-injection-based-on-run-time-values/).

Having said that, with unit tests I would simply inject my fakes in the classes that are under test. Unit tests are there to still prove to yourself and your co-workers that the code still does as intended.
 And with integration tests I would make a special StartUp class with all my fakes and give it to the test host as ASP.NET Core allows you to do. You can read more about the test host here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html

Hope this helps.

**Update** Added cast to interface because the ternary conditional has no way of telling. Plus added some basic samples.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I'm trying to implement your suggestions, but it is giving me a weird error. (probably it is not in your logic, but at my side.) once i'm successful, I'll mark the answer. and the error is: `..There is no implicit conversion between TaskRepositoryFake and TaskRepository`. I have exactly the same implementation as i mentioned in question. I'm looking into it at my end, meanwhile can you confirm once again, if it allows this in this specific scenario.

Comment: Well, I now notice that ITaskRepository is a class. Did you mean interface? Other than that it seems you didn't exactly copy the code above. Because in my line of code it would never try to convert a TaskRepository to a TaskRepositoryFake (or vice versa). So please check it carefully.

Comment: It's a typo here. `ITaskRepository` is actually an interface. Otherwise I would be getting compile time errors, as class cannot have only methods signature, but definition as well. I am exactly using the logic you provided, but still above error :( .. Technically, there shouldn't be such error, as `TaskRepository` and `TaskRepositoryFake`, both implement `ITaskRepository` interface.

Comment: I appologize. With ternary conditions you need to explicitly cast it. See update. I also provided a more complete basic sample for the use case. You should be good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject your dependencies configuration based, or environment based, or both.

Option 1 : Environment Based

```
    public IHostingEnvironment env{ get; set; }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    } 
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // register other fake dependencies
            services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepositoryFake>();
        }
        else
        {
            // register other real dependencies
            services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Option 2 : Configuration Based

```
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public Startup()
    {
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
       Configuration = builder.Build();
    } 

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var isFakeMode= Configuration["ServiceRegistrationMode"] == "Fake";
        if (isFakeMode)
        {
            // register other fake dependencies
            services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepositoryFake>();
        }
        else
        {
            // register other real dependencies
            services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Option 3 : Environment Based + Configuration Based

```
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public IHostingEnvironment env{ get; set; }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    } 
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var isFakeMode = Configuration["ServiceRegistrationMode"] == "Fake";
        if (env.IsDevelopment() && isFakeMode)
        {
            // register other fake dependencies
            services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepositoryFake>();
        }
        else
        {
            // register other real dependencies
            services.AddSingleton<ITasksRepository, TasksRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't allow `ConfigureServices` to have more than one params, and throws exception: `System.InvalidOperationException`, with message, 
`The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection.`

Comment: Thanks Adem. But there still is problem in Option 1 and Option 3. Where do you get the variable `env` from? It is not defined in scope, hence gives exception

Comment: better way to do that is by setting different env: Testing, Development, Staging.
applying [startup conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#startup-conventions)
and you can reduce the `if clause`, i.e.
`ConfigureTestingServices` & `ConfigureDevelopmentServices`